# Time Fields only in grails

Tags: grails, time, datepicker

I have domain class that uses

```
  Date StartTime
  Date endTime
```

E.g 9:00:00 , 15:00:00

What do i use in grails for just timePicker and not have dates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing out of the box in Grails.

Instead you can use any JS-timepicker, like http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html . This one is really simple to use.
Of course you have to do date parsing and formatting on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a plugin, have a look at the [**Joda-Time Plugin**](http://www.grails.org/plugin/joda-time) and its [**documentation**](http://gpc.github.io/grails-joda-time/).

In your domain class you can do

```
DateTime startTime
DateTime endTime
```

Then in your views use the **joda:dateTimePicker** or  **joda:datePicker** or **joda:timePicker** as guided in documentation.